# Now, how is Lucene.NET utilized on StackOverflow (part 2)?

Tags: discussion, search, architecture, lucene

Given that [StackOverflow has moved over to Lucene.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) for search, the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39950/how-is-lucene-net-utilized-on-stackoverflow-if-at-all) that I asked on this matter now has a completely different answer.

Specifically, some of the things I'd like to know are:

- How are the indexes arranged?
- What is the structure of the documents?
- Was a custom scorer written to somehow weigh results differently based on vote data?  If so, how was that scorer implemented?
- What kind of boosts are applied and on what level?
- Custom analyzers or no?
- [Anything else that might be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297794/how-would-one-use-lucene-to-help-implement-search-on-a-site-like-stackoverflow).

Comment: I may answer this a bit later on, I'm not sure in how much detail - since there's quite a bit of domain knowledge and explanation required to understand *why* certain aspects are the way they are.  Also, we're currently in flux at the moment, moving to a parser for our advanced terms is on my todo.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Well, anytime you want to get around to it =P

Comment: Update status: it's not!

Comment: @nickcraver might change to ask about elastic search, as many of the concepts are carried over.  When I'm at a proper computer I'll update.